# Jquery Resizable div jumps around

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable, bootstrap-table

I'm having a resizeable div inside a bootstrap table. When i resize the element either on the left or right handle i want the position to stay the same and have the div just move at the handle i'm resizing it with. However my div jumps around cause the table cells from bootstrap dont have a fixed width i guess. I can't figure out a way to let's say drag at the right side and have the left end of my div stay in position...

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="event">Content</div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#event').resizable({
    handles: "e,w"
});
```

CSS:

```
#event {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I also tried adding some position:absolute but the div still keeps jumping around.

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/59pa8d59/

Comment: it works if you set the width of the `<td>` like: `td{width: 60px;}` but I guess it's not the idea...